# Removing columns and sorting by Name in finger command

Tags: linux

When I use the `finger` command, it displays Login, Name, Tty, Idle, Login Time, Office, Office Phone, and Host. I just need the information in the Login, Name, Idle, and Login Time columns.

I tried using `awk` and `sed`, but they resulted in chart being all over the place (example below).

```
$ finger | sed -r 's/\S+//3'
    Login    Name                          Idle  Login Time   Office     Office Phone   Host
user1 Full  Name    pts/1      20  Feb 3 19:34                           (--------------------)
user2 FirstName  LastName            pts/2         Feb 3 17:04                           (--------------)
user3 Name  NameName    pts/3   1:11  Feb 2 11:37                           (-------------------------------)
user4 F  Last    pts/4   1:09  Feb 13 18:14                           (-------------------)
```

How do I go about removing specific columns while keeping the structure intact?

Comment: `finger` in 2020 ? Last time I saw something about this, that was like > 15 years ago. Moreover, we need your code, even failed attempts

Comment: I tried ` finger | sed -r 's/\S+//3'` to try removing the 3rd column first. What's a better alternative for the finger for collecting info about the users logged in?

Comment: What are you really trying to do ? What is the goal ? `w` seems more modern

Comment: It's for just communication purpose. So I needed to be able to associate the username with their full names and know if the user is currently online. I couldn't do that with `w` or `who` or with other commands that display user login information for some reason. Only `pinky` and `finger` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot extract particular fields based on whitespace separator, because on certain rows the columns might be blank and contain only whitespace, especially the `Idle` column, which will be blank for sessions with limited idle time.  (An additional problem is that the real name field may contain a variable number of spaces.)

So you may have to resort to `cut -b ...` using hard-coded byte offsets.  The following seems to work on my system, as `finger` seems to use a fixed format output, truncating real names etc as needed, so the byte offsets do not change if the length of the GECOS (real name) field of logged in users is changed.

```
finger | cut -b 1-20,30-48
```

Note that it will be inherently fragile if the format of the `finger` command output were to change in future.  You might be able to produce something slightly more robust using regular expression parsing, for example parsing the column headings (first line of `finger` output) to obtain the byte offsets rather than hard-coding them, but it will still be somewhat fragile.  A more robust solution would involve writing your own code to obtain information from the same sources that `finger` uses, and use that in place of `finger`.  The existing code of an open-source implementation of `finger` might be a suitable starting point, and then you can adapt it to remove the columns that are not of interest.

---

Update: building a patched version of `finger`.

Save this patch as `/tmp/patch`.  It it just a quick-and-dirty patch to suppress certain fields from being printed; they are still calculated.

```
--- sprint.c~   2020-06-13 12:27:12.000000000 +0100
+++ sprint.c    2020-06-13 12:32:23.363138500 +0100
@@ -89,7 +89,7 @@
    if (maxlname + maxrname < space-2) { maxlname++; maxrname++; }

    (void)xprintf("%-*s %-*s %s\n", maxlname, "Login", maxrname,
-       "Name", " Tty      Idle  Login Time   Office     Office Phone");
+       "Name", " Idle  Login Time");
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < entries; ++cnt) {
        pn = list[cnt];
        for (w = pn->whead; w != NULL; w = w->next) {
@@ -100,12 +100,6 @@
                (void)xprintf("  *     *  No logins   ");
                goto office;
            }
-           (void)xputc(w->info == LOGGEDIN && !w->writable ?
-                   '*' : ' ');
-           if (*w->tty)
-               (void)xprintf("%-7.7s ", w->tty);
-           else
-               (void)xprintf("        ");
            if (w->info == LOGGEDIN) {
                stimeprint(w);
                (void)xprintf("  ");
@@ -118,17 +112,6 @@
            else
                (void)xprintf(" %.5s", p + 11);
 office:
-           if (w->host[0] != '\0') {
-               xprintf(" (%s)", w->host);
-           } else {
-           if (pn->office)
-               (void)xprintf(" %-10.10s", pn->office);
-           else if (pn->officephone)
-               (void)xprintf(" %-10.10s", " ");
-           if (pn->officephone)
-               (void)xprintf(" %-.14s",
-                   prphone(pn->officephone));
-           }
            xputc('\n');
        }
    }
```

Then obtain the source code, patch it and build it. (Change `destdir` as required.)

```
apt-get source finger
cd bsd-finger-0.17/
pushd finger
patch -p0 < /tmp/patch
popd
destdir=/tmp/finger
mkdir -p $destdir/man/man8 $destdir/sbin $destdir/bin
./configure --prefix=$destdir
make
make install
```

And run it...

```
$destdir/bin/finger
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` for the sake of dpkg dependencies management. And for who need, pushd/popd is just like `cd dir; cd -`

Comment: @GillesQuenot I hadn't come across `cd -` but although the distinction doesn't matter here, it looks like issuing it repeatedly will just oscillate between the last 2 directories, whereas `pushd` and `popd` maintains a stack as the name suggests. Still, `cd -` certainly looks useful for interactive use to undo an unintentional `cd`, so I've learnt something handy.

Comment: I just prefer `cd` because `pushd/popd` produce annoying output

Answer (score 2):

Basically, to treat columns, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is the way to go,

ex: remove third column

```
finger | awk '{$3="";print}'
```

Comment: The problem is that some rows may have only whitespace in certain columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: If you found this informations, they have to be wrote somewhere in the system. Using `who`, `awk` and `cut` :

The informations can be gathered by `getent passwd`.

Created a test user with `adduser` :

```
# adduser foobar
Adding user `foobar' ...
Adding new group `foobar' (1001) ...
Adding new user `foobar' (1001) with group `foobar' ...
Creating home directory `/home/foobar' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for foobar
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: Jean-Charles De la tour
    Room Number []: 42
    Work Phone []: +33140000000
    Home Phone []: +33141000000
    Other []: sysadmin
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

And the new line in `/etc/passwd` file:

```
foobar:x:1001:1001:Jean-Charles De la tour,42,+33140000000,+33141000000,sysadmin:/home/foobar:/bin/bash
```

So it's easy to retrieve in formations from this:

```
for u in $(who | cut -d' ' -f1); do # iterate over connected users
    getent passwd | awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS='\n' -v u="$u" '$1==u{print "user: "$1, "full name: "$5, "room: "$6, "work phone : "$7, "home phone: "$8, "other: "$9}'
done
```

Just make sure you have `,` in `$5` column.

### Output

```
user: foobar
full name: Jean-Charles De la tour
room: 42
work phone : +33140000000
home phone: +33141000000
other: sysadmin
```

Comment: You might want to use `getent passwd` in case the system is using user information managed via NIS / LDAP and the like, not necessarily just the local `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Ah, sorry misread, you are using `who` to extract the information.